# Modified pre-order tree traversal - order children by score

Tags: php, mysql, modified-preorder-tree-t

So I have been able to output the data how I want except now I want to be able to rearrange it depending on the score of individual items. So right now I output something like this:

```
<ol>
 Item1
    <ol>
     subitem1A
        <ol>
         subsubitem1A
        </ol>
    </ol>
    <ol>
     subitem1B
    </ol>
</ol>
<ol>
 Item2
</ol>
```

I get that by putting the left and right values in an array and iterating through it. If it is a left value, it puts out `<ol>item` and if it is right it closes it with `</ol>`

Using the example above, what I want to do is if `Item2` has a better score than `Item1`, `Item2` will be first and `Item1` with all its children will be after it. If `subitem1B` has a better score than `subitem1A`, `subitem1B` will be before `subitem1A` and all its children.

I'm not sure if I would have to do something with the DB query or something before running the loop that puts all the html in a variable for output, but I was thinking along the lines if I had the output somehow I could check for any `<ol>` that are direct children of the parent `<ol>`. So if I look at `subitem1A` and see its parent is `Item1` then look for any `<ol>` who has parent `Item1`, check the score, and then order accordingly. I don't know if that is possible but it was my thought process.

edit - Adding more info as requested.

I do this query:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE uCId = '$uCId' AND lft BETWEEN 2 AND '$max' ORDER BY lft ASC";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
```

Then:

```
$ol = array();
$html = "";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {          
        $ol[$row['lft']] = array('type'=>'open',
                                    'text'=>$row['text']
                                    //and more stuff like score, date, etc 
                                    );
        $ol[$row['rgt']]  = array('type'=>'close');
    }
$olCount = count($ol);
for ($d=2; $d<=$olCount; $d++) {
        if ($ol[$d]['type'] == 'open') {
            $html.= '<ol>various html'.$ol[$d]['text'].'various html';
                    }else{
                          $html .= '</ol>';
                    }
```

Basically I just left out some html which would just make things harder to read. The score can be placed anywhere it would need to be. the id for the `<ol>` could be the score or anything. Whatever would work.

Comment: Can you provide source code ?

Comment: @safarov I have posted everything I believe will be relevant.